# Button that takes a screenshot and sends that in an email

Tags: java, php, javascript, html

I am making a delivery-form; I want that when I press a button the entire site will be captured and will be sent to a predefined email address. Is this possible to do?
If so, how?

This is the site http://finefoodandwine.nl/Restaurant-Veldhoven/bestelformulier.php
I also need to make that the buttons only appear when all the name and address details are filled in, but that's for later concern.

Comment: You want the make an image from the whole site and mail the image? I can't believe anybody want that..

Comment: indeed, I want the customer to have no hassle sending the required information to me. Well I only need the text, it would be ideal if I could get the picture to look like the print button.

Comment: If you realy want this, I advice you to have a look at http://princexml.com/ This helps you to convert your HTML into PDF. This PDF you can send easy via PHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible.

You need to process the data that the user has inserted into the form and send it away with PHP.

You can use the mail functions within PHP

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Comment: I don't think the data processed by java, can be processed by doing this? But there is no smart solution besides asking the customer to screenshot their screen and paste it into the mail?

Comment: Yes their is, get the data using [post](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) and process the data with the mail function.

Answer (score 2):

i hope you don't want to make a screenshot to see the order. if so, just submit the values via php/mail.

Making a screenshot isn't impossible but it's very difficult, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/6678156/425005

Comment: Wow this is cool http://experiments.hertzen.com/jsfeedback/ (from your link)

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible. The browser runs in a sandbox, and has (thank God) no access (html5: very limited access) to local resources.

Comment: Alternatively, you could have your clients download a program to create a screenshot if that's an option.

Comment: I understand the concern about personal invasion, but it's either this or printing it out and handing it over personally, emailing it would make it much easier for them.

Comment: @user1477388 than I could just make them ask to make a screenshot, and paste it in the mail.

Comment: Everyone is emailing orders. What is so special in Veldhoven (I am in Helmond) that this cannot be done?

Comment: `No, this is not possible` Tunnel vision

Comment: I am not sure I understand the requirement.  If you want to capture a screenshot with PHP, you can do that like this http://www.google.com/search?q=php+screenshot&aq=f&sugexp=chrome,mod=1&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8.  If you want to capture what a user sees on the client's machine, you will have to have the user do it themselves, or click a button and take the screenshot with AJAX, PHP or something like that.

Comment: @JvdBerg I thought that was the (thank god) was ment for.